# Can't connect Google Cloud Platform VM to MySQL DB through PHP file

Tags: php, mysql, database, virtual-machine, google-cloud-platform

Trying to connect to a SQL db hosted on google cloud platform.
Can connect to the db from within the VM instances terminal but cannot connect to the database through a php file.

Have a php file called phpinfo.php that contains

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
if (!$conn){
    die("Connect failed" . $conn->connect_error);
}
echo "connected";
```

I have an echo before this code that is printed but then it doesn't return if it has connected to the db or not.

Comment: You missed a comma after `$username`

Comment: sorry that was a typo, there is a comma in our code .... anything else you can see ?

Comment: change `$conn->connec_error` to `$conn->connect_error`

Comment: unfortunately that was also a typo :( is there anything else ? :)

Comment: what value are you using for $servername. are you connecting to mysql server through a TCP socket or a Unix socket. If you are connecting through a TCP socket, then you should be able to telnet to $servername from the terminal of your VM. For example try this command: telnet $servername 3306